# Returning errors into templates

Tags: plugin-development, error-message, error-templates, error

When working with a custom form that posts to a plugin function - what's the best way to return errors that would be displayed like the [forgot password](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/forgot-password-form) code example below

```
    {% if errors is defined %}
        <ul class="errors">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Possible dupe? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4889/how-to-return-errors-from-a-model-back-to-the-template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just return the form model object back to the template. Yii has built in validation and error handling within the models themselves. In the example `email` is the instance of your form's model.

The template:

```
{% if email is not defined %}
    {% set email = craft.postmaster.email() %}
{% endif %}

{% for error in email.getAllErrors() %}
    <p>{{ error }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<p>
    <label for="toEmail">To Email</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="toEmail" name="toEmail" value="{{ email.toEmail }}" />
    {% if email.getError('toEmail') %}
    <label for="toEmail">{{ email.getError('toEmail') }}</label>
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

The controller:

```
$model = new Postmaster_EmailFormModel(craft()->request->getPost());

if(!$model->validate())
{ 
    // Prepare a flash error message for the user.
    craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('The email could not be sent.'));

    craft()->urlManager->setRouteVariables(array(
        'email' => $model
    ));
}
else
{
    $event = new Event($this, array(
        'email' => $model
    ));

    craft()->postmaster_forms->onEmailFormSend($event);

    $this->redirect(craft()->request->getPost('redirect'));
}
```